# Ho to convert an xml file to map[string]interface{} in golang?

Tags: xml, go

I know the method `Unmarshal` in `encoding/json` can convert a json to `map[string]interface{}`, so I also want to do same thing with `encoding/xml`, but it failed.

It seems `encoding/xml` do not have the similar method, do any one know how to solve it? I don't want to define struct for the xml content, since the xml is generated by many different services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no generic way to convert XML to a map. What is it you want to be the keys and values?

Comment: Also asked (and answered) [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/zEmDOp_yFpU/discussion).